# What are the names of these karakul hats among the Hasidim?

Tags: clothing, chasidut-hasidism, hats

[image]

Hats of two men in the foreground.

Answer (score 3):

Chasidim call them a Kutchma.

[See here](https://www.instagram.com/p/Beofaw-lE5h/?hl=en)